# hibernate reverse engineering on DB2/Zos very very slow.

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipse-plugin, db2

Im new to hibernate but I have used the reverse from hibernate tools  with eclipse on a ms sql box it work very nice. I now wanted to use it to make entity classes from db2 on z/os. This taking over twenty minutes and still not returning the tables to wizard. I have included a default schema thought it would help, the schema consist of 350 tables. Still taking every long. I can watch the open/fetch on zos. I can also just use JPA/EclipseLink to make entity classes and it works fast.

Is a way I can write out logs for hibernate tools just to see what it is asking DB2 for and also any performance tips would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe the Eclipse Hibernate Tools use Dali's wizard. If so: Dali uses the Eclipse DTP project to fetch the DB2 metadata. You might open the DTP Data Source Explorer view and expand your database's tree. If the view's performance is terrible, the problem is with DTP; otherwise it is a problem with either Dali or the Hibernate Tools extensions to Dali. To narrow it down further, you could try to generate your model using vanilla Eclipse for Java EE (i.e. without the Hibernate Tools extensions etc.).

Comment: The DTP explorer works well I use it often.

Comment: I gave that suggestion because Dali has had problems in the past querying metadata from various DTP "drivers". Problematic drivers can query  for the metadata from *all* the tables on your database, sometimes affecting performance. Have you tried using Dali in a vanilla Eclipse for Java EE? If you have the time, it's not too difficult to add your DB2 driver definition, add a new empty JPA project, and generate your model from your database schema. Just trying to narrow down the problem....

Comment: It works good using JPA. Pretty fast even in my current version of kepler with several plugins.Looks like Dali could be blamed.

Comment: Maybe I was not very clear earlier: Dali is an Eclipse project. It ships with the base "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" package you download from eclipse.org. By default it supports JPA spec-compliant projects. It also ships with an EclipseLink extension. Hibernate Tools extends Dali to provide support for Hibernate-specific features. If you can create your Entities from your DB2 database using the base "Eclipse Java EE" package, and you have no performance problems; then the problem most likely lies with Hibernate Tools; and you might want to contact the vendor (i.e. JBoss/RedHat).